# Blowfish decode from a string

Tags: php, base64, session-variables, pear, blowfish

Using the blowfish cbc mode, I want to create an encrypted token. When I create the token and immediately decrypt it, it works correctly. However, if I place the encrypted token in `SESSION` and try to decrypt it during a subsequent request, the decryption produces garbage.

This is my code. I am using `SESSION` for testing; eventually, I'll be storing these strings in a database instead.

```
session_start();
define("key","v8nga4r76qlipm111jnioool");
define("iv",substr(md5(uniqid(rand(),1)),0,8));
require_once("Crypt/Blowfish.php");

$str = "Blowfish_test";
// encode start!!
$blowfish = Crypt_Blowfish::factory("cbc", key, iv);
$encrypt = $blowfish->encrypt($str);
$encrypt64 = base64_encode($encrypt);
$_SESSION["test"] = $encrypt64;
```

So far, everything is correct. If, on the same request, I immediately decode it (from `SESSION`), the results are as expected:

```
// decode start!!
$blowfish = Crypt_Blowfish::factory("cbc", key, iv);
$decrypt64 = base64_decode($_SESSION["test"]);
$decrypt = $blowfish->decrypt($decrypt64);
$trim_decrypt = rtrim($decrypt, "\0");
echo "Before encryption : " . $str ."<br>";
echo "Encrypted string &nbsp&nbsp: " .$encrypt64. "<br>";
echo "decrypted string &nbsp&nbsp: " .$trim_decrypt. "<br>";
```

If I place only the second block of code on a different page (so a previously generated string is being decrypted), the decrypted string is garbage.

Encryption -> session["test"] -> Decryption　--- no problem

session["test"] -> Decryption --- problem

What's happening here?

Comment: Um, you're defining `iv`, which I assume is your initialization vector, as a big random blob every request. It needs to be the same across requests. And please don't include YouTube videos in your questions. We believe you, we don't need video evidence of the symptoms you describe.

Comment: First of all,Thank you for the translation.
In your opinion, I was able to solve the problem.
As you say, initialization vector values had to be decrypted at the same value.
I was able to solve the problem, and thank you!!
So that might be useful for someone, i add the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for this super delay.
I solved this problem by the comment at that time, so I close this question using community wiki.

--- add ---
problem is solved

```
// encode
// At the same time save the initialization vector
$_SESSION["test"] = $encrypt64;
$_SESSION["iv"]   = iv;

--- other file ---
// decode
$blowfish = Crypt_Blowfish::factory("cbc", key, $_SESSION["iv"]);
```